# Why /usr/local/bin isn't in the path by default?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, posix

When I install third-party stuff on my Ubuntu, the default prefix is /usr/local, however, this path isn't on the PATH by default.

How should I put it on the PATH for all users and why isn't the default behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Ubuntu are you running?

What do you see when you run this?:

```
$ more /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
```

Or are you saying that the executable file gets installed directly in `/usr/local/[CMDNAME]` rather than in `/usr/local/bin/[CMDNAME]` ?